# Redirect авторизованного пользователя, когда тот снова хочет попасть на страницу авторизации

Tags: spring, безопасность

Есть простенький сайтик, на котором есть страница приветствия (/welcome) с двумя ссылками на авторизацию(/login) и регистрацию(/sign). Если пользователь не авторизован, на другие страницы его не пускает - перенаправляет на страницу авторизации.

```
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/welcome", "/login", "/sign").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/main").authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/main")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/welcome")
            .permitAll();
```

Вот моя конфигурация. 
А теперь, собственно, о проблеме. Когда пользователь авторизован, то ему все равно остаются доступны страницы приветствия, авторизации и регистрации. Например, пользователь вошел на сайт под своим логином и паролем, потом перешел через строку браузера на страницу авторизации и еще раз вошел. Я бы хотел оградиться от такого редиректом с эти трех начальных страниц на /main, но только, если пользователь авторизован. Подскажите, есть ли способ редиректить через конфигурацию или есть другой способ лучше и проще?

Comment: `.antMatchers("/", "/welcome", "/login", "/sign").permitAll()`. `permitAll()` заменить на роль `ANONYMOUS`

Comment: @Tsyklop да, это я уже пробовал сделать, выскакивает ошибка 403, отказано в доступе, но вот можно ли сделать так, чтобы ошибка не выскакивала, чтобы не смущать пользователей, а сразу редиректило куда надо? Или стоит писать обработчик ошибки или даже в контроллер пихать логику редиректа?

Comment: К сожалению придется писать это в контроллере. Проверяешь на авторизацию, если авторизован редирект